# If statement after default switch case - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, printing, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm working on a Java program and I'm struggling with creating what I'm calling the statistical area for my program. I've created a "Rock" "Paper" "Scissors" program and I'm trying to tell the user how many times they won and how many times the computer won and finally, how many ties there were.

Please excuse my ignorance, I'm learning. Here's my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TheAntlers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int playerHumanWins = 0;
        int playerComputerWins = 0;
        int numberOfTies = 0;
        int computerResult;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {

            String startGame;
            String playerHuman;
            String playerComputer = " ";

            System.out.print("Do you want to play \"Rock\", \"Paper\", \"Scissors\"? (Y/N): ");
            startGame = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            if(startGame.equals("N")) {
                System.out.println("NO!");
                break;
            }
            else if(! startGame.equals("Y")) {
                startGame = startGame.toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Sorry, " + startGame + " is not a valid entry...");               
            }
            while(startGame.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.print("Please choose \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\": ");
                playerHuman = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

                computerResult = (int)(Math.random() * 3);

                if(computerResult == 0) {
                    playerComputer = "ROCK";
                }
                else if(computerResult == 1) {
                    playerComputer = "PAPER";
                }
                else if (computerResult == 2) {
                    playerComputer = "SCISSORS";
                }

                switch (playerHuman) {
                    case "ROCK" :
                        if(playerComputer.equals(playerHuman)) {
                        System.out.println("Tie you both picked \"ROCK\"");
                        numberOfTies++;
                    }
                        else if(playerComputer.equals("PAPER")) {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, the computer wins!");
                            playerComputerWins++;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("You win, \"ROCK\" beats " + "\"" + playerComputer + "\"");
                            playerHumanWins++;
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "PAPER" :
                        if(playerComputer.equals(playerHuman)) {
                        System.out.println("Tie you both picked \"PAPER\"");
                        numberOfTies++;
                    }
                        else if(playerComputer.equals("ROCK")) {
                            System.out.println("You win, \"PAPER\" beats " + "\"" + playerComputer + "\"");
                            playerHumanWins++;
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, the computer won!");
                            playerComputerWins++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "SCISSORS" :
                        if(playerComputer.equals(playerHuman)) {
                        System.out.println("Tie you both picked \"SCISSORS\"");
                        numberOfTies++;
                    }
                        else if(playerComputer.equals("PAPER")) {
                            System.out.println("You win, \"SCISSORS\" beats " + "\"" + playerComputer + "\"");
                            playerHumanWins++;
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Sorry, the computer won!");
                            playerComputerWins++;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        playerHuman = playerHuman.toLowerCase();
                        System.out.println("Sorry, " + playerHuman + " is not a valid entry...");      
                }

                if(playerHumanWins == 1) {
                    System.out.println("You won: " + playerHumanWins + " times");
                    System.out.println("The computer won " + playerComputerWins + " times");
                    System.out.println("There were " + numberOfTies++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Basically I've made an if statement that says when the user wins at least once, display the statistics** However this doesn't seem to work. I'm not 100% sure how I can get the statistics to display.

Comment: The `return` statements aren't going to be of help to you

Comment: @MadProgrammer How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the `return` statements in your code and forcing Java to exit your (`main`) method, which is preventing it from executing you "statistics" section of the code and terminating your program.

Start by removing them.

Also...

```
if (playerHumanWins == 1) {...
```

Means that the statistics will only be displayed once, when the first time the player wins.  Not sure if this is really want you want or not...

**Updated**

Based on the condition that the game can only end until if the player wins a game, you could do something like...

```
    if (playerHumanWins == 1) {
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("You won: " + playerHumanWins + " times");
System.out.println("The computer won " + playerComputerWins + " times");
System.out.println("There were " + numberOfTies++);
```

Or...

```
while (startGame.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && playerHumanWins < 1) {
    //...
}

System.out.println("You won: " + playerHumanWins + " times");
System.out.println("The computer won " + playerComputerWins + " times");
System.out.println("There were " + numberOfTies++);
```

Either way, you should also get rid of the `while (true) {` statement, its adding unnecessary complications...

Comment: Once the user wins the program terminates. So it might take them 9 losses to the computer and 12 ties first before they win so in the end it should say computer - 12 ties - 9 and wins - 1 etc..

Comment: So the only way to stop a game is to win?

Comment: Yes, the only way to stop the game is to win the game.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. What would you suggest instead of while(true)?

Comment: I wouldn't.  Just leave it out.  Once you leave the (currently) second loop, you should exit the game...?  You could change the logic to use a `do-while` instead...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `return` to jump out of switch. Return exits the method. How about using `break` instead !

Also make sure to reset the value of playerHumanWins and others back to zero before you play a new game

Comment: I would check the logic of the code first.  All the `return` statements I could find were within `if-else` blocks...

Answer (score 0):

Modify some change as follows:

From

```
 else if(! startGame.equals("Y")) {
     startGame = startGame.**toLowerCase()**;
     System.out.println("Sorry, " + startGame + " is not a valid entry...");               
 }
```

To

```
else if(! startGame.equals("Y")) {
    startGame = startGame.**toUpperCase()**;
    System.out.println("Sorry, " + startGame + " is not a valid entry...");               
}
```

Comment: this change only affects the case of echoed output when the user enters invalid selection - completely irrelevant to the question